# JMenuBar abstract button factory does not add buttons

Tags: java, swing, generics, abstract-class, jmenubar

I have written a class that should create abstract menu items using a factory method, but the components never show up in the menubar. I have stepped through the debugger and the properties, such as text, were not being set. I have tried invalidating the component with no luck.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameMenu extends JMenuBar {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8058207339633024354L;

    private JMenu file;
    private JMenu help;
    private JMenuItem newGame;
    private JMenuItem about;

    private static NewGameAction newGameAction = new NewGameAction();
    private static AboutAction aboutAction = new AboutAction();

    public GameMenu() {
        super();

        file = (JMenu) createButton(JMenu.class, "File",
            KeyEvent.VK_F, this, null);
        help = (JMenu) createButton(JMenu.class, "Help",
            KeyEvent.VK_H, this, null);
        newGame = (JMenuItem) createButton(JMenuItem.class, "New Game",
            KeyEvent.VK_N, file, newGameAction);
        about = (JMenuItem) createButton(JMenuItem.class, "About",
            KeyEvent.VK_A, help, aboutAction);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends AbstractButton> AbstractButton createButton(
            Class<T> buttonClazz, String text, int mnemonic, JComponent parent,
            Action action) {
        AbstractButton button = null;

        try {
            button = buttonClazz.newInstance();
            button.setText(text);
            button.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
            button.setAction(action);
            button.invalidate();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (T) parent.add(button);
    }

    private static class AboutAction extends AbstractAction {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("About");
        }
    }

    private static class NewGameAction extends AbstractAction {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("New Game");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Abstract Menu Test");
                GameMenu menu = new GameMenu();

                f.setJMenuBar(menu);
                f.setSize(300, 200);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Adding the components manually seems to work fine, but this is not desirable for my situation.

```
public GameMenu() {
    super();

    file = new JMenu("File");
    file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
    this.add(file);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably because you are setting `null` actions and by that resetting the text and mnemonic on the buttons that are created in `createButton()`.  Comment out the following line:

```
button.setAction(action);
```

And you should see the menu OK.

[image]

See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for some examples on how to define and work with actions.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for that. I just moved the `setAction()` line after the `newInstance()` line. That way, setting text and mnemonic can override the action properties. You *could* change your answer to that if you want.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl You are welcome! Yes that would also solve the immediate problem :) But why would you want to override the action arguments, and why would you set the null action?

Comment: The `null` are placeholders, I was adding the actions later. I am just creating a `private static NewGameAction extends AbstractAction {}` right inside the class.

Comment: I added actions for the `JMenuItem` buttons so that they are not all `null`.